# Curv view at the bottom of the uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I need to draw a view with UIBezierPath at the bottom of the view just like this image.
[image]

I try with this code but oval draw at the half of the image not at bottom of the view like in picture
Here is my output and code

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: imgCamera.layer)
    shapeLayer.path = self.pathCurvedForView(givenView: imgCamera).cgPath
    shapeLayer.frame = imgCamera.bounds
    shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
    imgCamera.layer.mask = shapeLayer

}

private func pathCurvedForView(givenView: UIView) ->UIBezierPath
{
    let ovalRect = givenView.frame

    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath()

    ovalPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: ovalRect.midX, y: ovalRect.midY), radius: ovalRect.width / 2, startAngle: 0 * CGFloat.pi/180, endAngle: -180 * CGFloat.pi/180, clockwise: true)
    ovalPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ovalRect.midX, y: ovalRect.midY))

    ovalPath.close()

    UIColor.gray.setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()

    return ovalPath
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can add a rectangle instead as subView and using the parentView maskToBounds  to achieve that effect

Comment: I know that you have marked another answer as accepted, but did you try my answer? and another question why do you prefer that answer before my answer? Its only a curiosity matter

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks for asking actually first i need to go with layer approach in which i already at half way but not able to success on it so i check daiya_boy approach but  it also not working because of my error so i not try your answer because you both have same approach.

Comment: ok dude thanks for answering btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code Work:**

```
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width/2
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = imageView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, lightBlack.cgColor , lightBlack.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [NSNumber(value: 0.0), NSNumber(value: 0.5), NSNumber(value: 0.75),NSNumber(value: 0.75), NSNumber(value: 1.0)]
    imageView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Another view is not required, because ImageView is a UIView itself, only must be touchable, you are adding another view to make the white border?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I added above view to make bottom partially black layout (as you can see). there is only one button ahead of it that shows camera image.

Comment: Its another way to do this, ok

Comment: @ReinierMelian Actually you'r right let me edit my answer.

Comment: @chiragshah Check this [dump projct](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/Dump). Still not clear then ask.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thanks now it is working i forgot to make clip to bound true

Answer (score 1):

You can add the cam `UIButton` directly as subView instead and using the `UIImageView` `maskToBounds` to achieve that effect, adding border width and border color to the `UIImageView` and making the `UIImageView` touchable is enough

**Example Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height/2
        self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.imageView.frame.size.height - self.imageView.frame.size.height * 0.2, width: self.imageView.frame.size.width, height: self.imageView.frame.size.height * 0.2)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chatBubbleChat2Filled"), for: .normal)
        self.imageView.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`startAngle` and `endAngle` are supposed to be values in radians. The angle calculation looks really weird in your case, what were you trying to achieve? To me, the desired output look like it needs an arc from 5/8 PI to 7/8 PI, counter-clockwise. In your case, it goes from 0 to ~-PI, clockwise.

Try

```
ovalPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: ovalRect.midX, y: ovalRect.midY), radius: ovalRect.width / 2, startAngle: CGFloat.pi * 5.0/8.0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 7.0/8.0, clockwise: false)
ovalPath.close()
```

You don't need to add `addLine` by the way, `close()` will do that fot you